# python change the return type from set to list

Tags: python

I make a code below and the return value now is a list of set, if I want to change the return value to return a list of list, is there any way to do this?

```py
class SetSuite:
    def __init__(self, list_of_lists):
        self.__data = []
        # looping through each list in list_of_lists, adding to set using add_set()
        for a_list in list_of_lists:
            self.add_set(a_list)

    # adds a list indicating a set of data into internal list of sets
    def add_set(self, a_list):
        # converting a_list to set and appending to data
        self.__data.append(set(a_list))

    # returns the list of sets
    def get_sets(self):
        return self.__data

    # returns the union set of all sets
    def union_all(self):
        # creating an empty set
        union_set = set()
        # looping through each set
        for a_set in self.__data:
            # finding union with current set, storing back in union_set
            union_set = union_set.union(a_set)
        return union_set

    # returns the intersection set of all sets
    def intersection_all(self):
        # if data list is empty, returning empty set
        if len(self.__data) == 0:
            return set()
        # otherwise taking first set from data list
        intersection_set = set(self.__data[0])
        # looping through remaining sets and performing intersection on each set,
        # storing the result in intersection_set itself
        for a_set in self.__data[1:]:
            intersection_set = intersection_set.intersection(a_set)
        # returning the set
        return intersection_set
```

Comment: Lots of your methods return something. Which one did you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

just return everything as a list  like this :

```
class SetSuite:
    def __init__(self, list_of_lists):
        self.__data = []
        # looping through each list in list_of_lists, adding to set using add_set()
        for a_list in list_of_lists:
            self.add_set(a_list)

    # adds a list indicating a set of data into internal list of sets
    def add_set(self, a_list):
        # converting a_list to set and appending to data
        self.__data.append(a_list)

    # returns the list of sets
    def get_sets(self):
        return self.__data

    # returns the union set of all sets
    def union_all(self):
        # creating an empty set
        union_set = set()
        # looping through each set
        for a_set in self.__data:
            # finding union with current set, storing back in union_set
            union_set = union_set.union(a_set)
        return list(union_set)

    # returns the intersection set of all sets
    def intersection_all(self):
        # if data list is empty, returning empty set
        if len(self.__data) == 0:
            return []
        # otherwise taking first set from data list
        intersection_set = set(self.__data[0])
        # looping through remaining sets and performing intersection on each set,
        # storing the result in intersection_set itself
        for a_set in self.__data[1:]:
            intersection_set = intersection_set.intersection(a_set)
        # returning the set
        return list(intersection_set)
```